# Android instantiate activity

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hy
I am new to Android programming and I try to add a secon activity to my AndroidManifest.xml
But now my application isnt starting any more.
The error is:

```
04-04 07:42:13.154: D/AndroidRuntime(809): Shutting down VM
04-04 07:42:13.154: W/dalvikvm(809): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.evo_soft/com.example.evo_soft.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.example.evo_soft.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:220)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
04-04 07:42:13.294: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  ... 11 more
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.evo_soft"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.evo_soft.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="group.pals.android.lib.ui.filechooser.FileChooserActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="user" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="group.pals.android.lib.ui.filechooser.services.LocalFileProvider"></service>
</application>
```

thanks for help

Markus

Comment: post the entire exception stacktrace, you might have a problem with the onCreate method implementation.

Comment: i'd guess you are using the context in the constructor of your mainactivity. don't. move the code that uses the context into onCreate for example.

Comment: thank you guys
i have found my error. it was at: Intent intent = new Intent(this, FileChooserActivity.class);